# Parallel processing in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, parallel-processing

I had a 'procedure A' in which it has to return a null cursor to front end and then immediately it should continue with the next step in which it will call a procedure which will take 20 min to complete the proc.

```
Procedure A(cur_out refcursor)
begin

 OPEN cur_out  for
 select 
 null empname,
 null empid
 from dual;

procedure B();//Will take 20 min

end;
```

Here the 'Procedure A' should return the null cursor without waiting for the 'Procedure B' to complete.

How to implement this in oracle.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7):

Assuming that you don't need procedure B to run in the same session as A, you can schedule the job to run asynchronously, i.e.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE a( p_cur_out OUT SYS_REFCURSOR )
AS
  l_jobno pls_integer;
BEGIN
  OPEN p_cur_out 
   FOR SELECT cast( null as varchar2(64) ) empname, 
              cast( null as integer ) empid
         FROM dual;

  dbms_job.submit( l_jobno,
                   'BEGIN B(); END;' );
  commit;
END a;
```

You'll return from A and a job will be scheduled immediately to run procedure B in a separate session (note that the job won't start until the current session commits which is why I added a commit here-- if your code is going to commit elsewhere, you can eliminate that).  All dbms_job.submit is doing is creating the job-- the job will not start executing until after the procedure returns.

If B takes arguments, you'll need to build the PL/SQL block dynamically.  So if B takes two NUMBER parameters

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE a( p_cur_out OUT SYS_REFCURSOR )
AS
  l_jobno  pls_integer;
  l_param1 pls_integer;
  l_param2 pls_integer;
BEGIN
  OPEN p_cur_out 
   FOR SELECT cast( null as varchar2(64) ) empname, 
              cast( null as integer ) empid
         FROM dual;

  dbms_job.submit( l_jobno,
                   'BEGIN B(' || to_char( l_param1 ) || ', ' ||
                                 to_char( l_param2 ) || '); END;' );
  commit;
END a;
```

Comment: I cannot think of any other way. Running the two "threads" in the same transaction seems completely impossible.

Comment: This is fine ...But a small doubt ..Do the 'Proecure a' will wait for the dbms_job.submit l_jobno,'BEGIN B(); END;' ); to complete or simply it will be triggered and the procedure a will be ended.

Comment: It waits for the DBMS_JOB.SUBMIT to complete, yes.  But that happens nearly instantaneously.  Procedure B will be executed some time later in a separate session.

Comment: One more doubt if the procedure B is having some arguments like B(arg1,arg2)...How to schedule the that procedure B with dbms_job.submit.......dbms_job.submit(l_jobno,'BEGIN B(arg1,arg2); END;);.........Since it throwing errors while passing these arguments in this way...do we need to follow some format while passing the arguments to the procedure B which is a dbms_job.

Comment: CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE a(l_param1 varchar2(20),
                              l_param2 varchar2(20), 
                               p_cur_out OUT SYS_REFCURSOR ) 
AS 
  l_jobno  pls_integer; 
   
BEGIN 
  OPEN p_cur_out  
   FOR SELECT cast( null as varchar2(64) ) empname,  
              cast( null as integer ) empid 
         FROM dual; 
 
  dbms_job.submit( l_jobno, 
                   'BEGIN B(' || l_param1 || ', ' || 
                                 l_param2 || '); END;' );
                                
  commit; 
END a;

Comment: this is how we are executing          ....................................declare

  TYPE gui_ref_cur IS REF CURSOR;
  p_cur_out gui_ref_cur;
 
BEGIN 

 A('MOBILE','10/5/2010 10:00:00 AM',p_cur_out);
END;
/..............................facing the following error.........................................................ORA-06550: line 1, column 148:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "10" when expecting one of the following:

   ) , * & | = - + < / > at in is mod remainder not rem => ..
   <an exponent (**)> <> or != or ~= >= <= <> and or

Comment: @K Ratnajyothi- Parameters to a stored procedure are declared as VARCHAR2, not VARCHAR2(20).

Comment: Corrected the declaration as varchar2 but not varchar2(20).......... Still it showing the same problem as mentioned. and aslo we are running the dbmsjob which was submitted as dbms_job.run(l_jobno);..............But not executed properly

Comment: Can you post the signature of B?  Are you expecting that the second parameter to A is really going to be a DATE?